# Block won't show beamer

Tags: beamer, block

I would like to display blocks with beamer, I took a code example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174257/blocks-in-beamer?newreg=c5f025179f7a476282806b244519b11f)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usetheme[secheader]{Boadilla}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title Frame}
    Introduction sentece
    \begin{block}{Title Block 1}
    {
        \begin{itemize}
        \item item 1
        \item item 2
        \end{itemize}
    }
    \end{block}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Title Block 2}
    {
        Text.
    }
    \end{exampleblock}
    \begin{alertblock}{Title Block 3}
    {
        You
    }
    \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However it displays this on my computer [image]

I tried several themes but the background blocks won't show.

Answer (score 1):

You use .dvi files (latex file.tex) you need to use .ps or .pdf files (pdflatex file.tex)

If you convert your file or directly use pdflatex command you will see the backgound and the border of the blocks

Comment: This makes very little sense... could you elaborate?

Comment: I think you're meaning that you shouldn't preview the DVI file, but only a PDF one. This is definitely true whenever the document uses graphic facilities.

Comment: I mean that the fact that the background and border of the block are not visible came from the format file, I had to convert it or to directly make a pdf

Comment: @x4rkz You may explicit commands:  to see correct result, use the compilation chain `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` or, directly, `pdflatex`.