# Multiple Blocks in first frame Beamer before begin document

Tags: beamer

[image]I need to make more boxes like the picture. I attached below in the first frame(The title) in my presentation in beamer. I mean I want to create more like this blue box where i can put my information, also I don't want to put them in the same frame.
I will attach a picture that I found on the internet to what I would like to do, also I will attach the code that I tried.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%Information to be included in the title page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{University}
\date{2021}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
   This is some text in the first frame. 
   This is some text in the first frame. 
   This is some text in the first frame.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you maybe looking for the `block` environment? There are some examples in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174261/118712 Also note that I you do not enter any text to the body of the block, you will have a block only in the darker color, which is likely your desired output.

Comment: There are also numerous packages that provide some kind of support for text in boxes, such as `tcolorbox` or `boiboites`, if you require more flexibility.

Comment: I need to do those multiple blocks in the first Title page and it doesn't work with \begin{block} and \end{block} because i need to do it before the table of contents and before the begin document. I want to right in evry block other informations so that I have 3 blocks in the same frame.

Comment: Sorry, I really do not understand what you are trying to do here or what the problem is. Can you maybe make a sketch or something?

Comment: I uploaded a picture of what I'm trying to do in the first frame, not necessarily this color. It's just an idea to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the following is closer to the expected output?

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{University}
\date{2021}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center, rounded=true, shadow=true]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vskip1em\par
    \setbeamercolor{author}{bg=structure!90!white,fg=white}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center, rounded=true, shadow=true]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \setbeamercolor{institute}{bg=structure!80!white,fg=white}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center, rounded=true, shadow=true]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \setbeamercolor{date}{bg=structure!60!white,fg=white}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center, rounded=true, shadow=true]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! yes this is what i was looking for. It worked, God Bless you!